# Cannot install jekyll on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, jekyll, ubuntu-17.10

Trying to install Jekyll but keep getting this error message:

```
current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20180219-16974-6pgqng.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... no
checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include,/usr/include/ffi... no
checking for shlwapi.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR="
Running autoreconf for libffi
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c/libffi/autogen.sh: 2:         exec: autoreconf: not found
libffi.mk:6: recipe for target '"/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-    1.9.21/ext/ffi_c/libffi-x86_64-linux-gnu"/.libs/libffi_convenience.a'     failed
make: *** ["/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c/libffi-x86_64-linux-gnu"/.libs/libffi_convenience.a] Error 127

make failed, exit code 2
```

I have installed the following but perhaps not in this order

- make
- build-essential
- ruby
- ruby-dev
- gcc

Any ideas?

Comment: `exec: autoreconf: not found` is the important part.

Answer (score 0):

## Solved!

had to run the command:

sudo apt-get install autoconf libtool